# Implementation of linux char driver with multiple parameters to access

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, ioctl

I am writing a simple char driver which accesses a PCI card. It is registered to sysfs with the help of a new class and accessible under `/dev/foodev`. Using standard file operations I can perform simple read and write operations to the device.

My problem: I have multiple parameters stored at different addresses on the card (version, status, control, ...) which I would like access independently. Currently having only one read and one write function I therefore have to change the address every time again in the driver code.
Obviously there is a more convenient way to implement this. I stumbled about the two following approaches and was wondering which is the better one in terms of sustainability and user accessibility:

- Using ioctl commands setting the address/parameter before an
  access.
- Having the device already nicely set up in udev using multiple attributes
  (`device_create_file()`) of which the user than just can write/read from
  different "files":

  `/dev/foodev
      ../version
      ../status
      ../control`

Comment: Don't (mis)use ioctls; you'll have race conditions.  Use the attributes as files.  That scheme is already used in sysfs.  E.G. look at GPIO LEDs and keys.

Comment: Plain and simple, haven't thought of race conditions, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look at the PCI framework to implement your driver.

Answer (score 0):

Don't (mis)use ioctls; you'll have race conditions. Use the attributes as files. That scheme is already used in sysfs. E.G. look at GPIO LEDs and keys. –  sawdust